# file:///android_asset does not work

Tags: android, android-assets

I store the images in assets/img/categories folder and trying to load them with this code:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(String.format("file:///android_asset/img/categories/%d.JPG", category.getId()), mImageIv);
```

It seems to be OK, but does not work:

```
E/ImageLoader(28790): /android_asset/img/categories/9.JPG: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ImageLoader(28790): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/img/categories/9.JPG: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: what wrong with using the `drawable` folder ?

Comment: @GirishNair There are about 1.5k images, which should be loaded dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the URI usage is something like this for assests folder

```
String imageUri = "assets://image.png";
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Just check [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples) reference

So your change your code something like this

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(String.format("assets:///img/categories/%d.JPG", category.getId()), mImageIv);
```

or even load it from SDCard like this

```
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png";
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 14):

`file:///android_asset` is only for use with `WebView`.

I do not know what `ImageLoader` is, but see if it accepts an `InputStream`. If so, use `AssetManager` and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on your desired asset.

Comment: Thanks. It's quite famous library Universal Image Loader.

So, if I want to use this library this way, I need to pre-copy assets to the external storage?

Comment: @RankoR: Universal Image Loader has its own `assets://` pseudo-scheme for assets, as is covered [in the documentation](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (simplified!) helper routine that will open the asset as an `InputStream` if the URI uses the `file:///android_asset/` pattern:

```
public static InputStream open(String urlString, Context context) throws IOException {
    URI uri = URI.create(urlString);

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("file") && uri.getPath().startsWith("/android_asset/")) {
        String path = uri.getPath().replace("/android_asset/", ""); // TODO: should be at start only
        return context.getAssets().open(path);
    } else {
        return uri.toURL().openStream();
    }
}
```

Usage like:

```
InputSteam is = Helper.open("file:///android_asset/img/categories/001.JPG", this); // "this" is an Activity, for example
```

Not shown: exception handling.