# Get some asset file path in APK

Tags: android, assets

I use some class. That's constructor needs some file path that contains some files.

ex)

```
Komoran komoran = new Komoran("D:\program_project\lib");
```

Now I'm making android app. so I can't use absolute path (Because other people who download my app don't have that folder and files)

so I decide to use 'assets' folder that is maybe in APK file. So, final code is like below.

```
Komoran komoran = new Komoran("file:///android_asset");
```

but It seems like folder path is wrong(this class doesn't work). What I did wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file:///android\_asset does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954878/file-android-asset-does-not-work)

Comment: there are many tutorials available here to read data from assest example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I read these two links. getAssets.open("filename") seems to work well. But what I need is folder path. I can't search the way. help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `"file:///android_asset"` path is used for applications which uses webview ex. cordova/phonegap. As it is part of resources because when Apk is created you can not use this path to access your assets folder. You have to work with `context.getResources().getAssets().open("fileName")`this code only.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe u can add this code: 
context.getResources().getAssets().open("fileName").
u will get a inputstream, and u can do something  u want.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use getResources. 
You can use directly

```
context.getAssets().open("fileName").
```